# SYB: can a map over the result of listify be rewritten with a gfoldl?

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, fold, scrap-your-boilerplate

Can I use SYB's gfoldl to do the map over the result of listify in one go?

Consider for example the following code:

```
extractNums :: Expr -> [Int]
extractNums e = map numVal $ listify isNum e

  where isNum :: Expr -> Bool
        isNum (Num _) = True
        isNum _       = False

        numVal :: Expr -> Int
        numVal (Num i) = i
        numVal _       = error "Somehow filter did not work?"
```

I do not like that in the numVal function I have to consider the different data constructors of the Expr type while I am only interested in the Num constructor. I rather would replace isNum and numVals with something like the vals function below:

```
    vals :: [Int] -> Expr -> [Int]
    vals xs (Num x) = x : xs
    vals xs _       = xs
```

Can this be done with gfoldl? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `listify` is defined as

```
-- | Get a list of all entities that meet a predicate
listify :: Typeable r => (r -> Bool) -> GenericQ [r]
listify p = everything (++) ([] `mkQ` (\x -> if p x then [x] else []))
```

which is similar to `filter`. We could create an alternative that resembles `mapMaybe` which combines `map` and `filter` you need into one:

```
import Data.Generics
import Data.Generics.Schemes
import Data.Maybe (maybeToList)
import Data.Typeable

listify' :: (Typeable t) => (t -> Maybe r) -> GenericQ [r]
listify' f = everything (++) ([] `mkQ` (maybeToList . f))
```

Then your example could be expressed as

```
numVal :: Expr -> Maybe Int
numVal (Num i) = Just i
numVal _       = Nothing

test :: Expr -> [Int]
test = listify' numVal
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's not the most elegant approach, but here's my attempt:

```
extractNums :: Expr -> [Int]
extractNums e = everything (++) (mkQ [] q) e
   where q (Num n) = [n]
         q _ = []
```

I expect its performance to be sub-par, though. Maye using `flip (++)` would be better? I can't see that right now.

On the other hand, I just realized `listify` is defined in a similar way. So it won't be worse than what you have right now, at least.

---

Alternatively, as suggested by @Alex below:

```
import qualified Data.DList as D

extractNums :: Expr -> [Int]
extractNums e = D.toList $ everything (D.append) (mkQ D.empty q) e
   where q (Num n) = D.singleton n
         q _ = D.empty
```

Comment: You could use something like a `DList` or a `Seq` from `Data.Sequence`. These have O(1) concatenation with only a single O(n)  conversion to a list.

Comment: @Alex I added a `DList` version. Also, it seems that `Seq`'s append is logarithmic, according to the docs.

Comment: I must have got the runtime of append confused with the runtime of snoc